# ASP.Net WCF service's Thread.CurrentPrincipal is being thrown away by some interceptor in a Federated (WIF) environment

Tags: wcf, wif, claims, federation

I have a per-call WCF service that's being hosted in IIS (.svc). In the service's constructor, I set *Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User* as per [this article](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Building-a-Silverlight-Line-Of-Business-Application-Part-3.aspx). In this case *HttpContext.Current.User* is of type *Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal* and has the claims that were sent back from my custom passive STS.

However, as soon as I step into my service operation and examine *Thread.CurrentPrincipal*, while this object is still of type *Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity*, the object itself is no longer the same as *HttpContext.Current.User* (**IsAuthenticated = false, AuthenticationType = "" and Name is null on Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity**), whereas these values are all still filled in correctly on *HttpContext.Current.User*. This tells me that something is intercepting the call to the operation and incorrectly changing the current principal to some generic, empty, unauthenticated claims principal.

I checked the thread ID in the constructor as well as in the operation and it's the same in both places, and evaluating *Thread.CurrentPrincipal* in the immediate window after assigning from *HttpContext.Current.User* shows that the thread identity is being set correctly in the constructor, so something is definitely executing in between the constructor and the method, and that something is changing my *Thread.CurrentPrincipal*.

Does anybody have any idea what is doing this, and how I can go about preventing / fixing this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When configuring a service for WIF federation, you call

```
FederatedServiceCredentials.ConfigureServiceHost(this);
```

Part of what this call does is to set up a custom *ServiceAuthorizationManager* of type *IdentityModelServiceAuthorizationManager* on the service host. This authorization manager appears to get called in between activation (construction) of the instance and execution of the operation, and it overwrites *Thread.CurrentPrincipal* with an instance of *IClaimsPrincipal*, but it doesn't seem to realize that it's running in ASP.NET Compatibility mode, so it doesn't pull the principal from *HttpContext.Current.User*.

I was able to bypass this behaviour by deriving from *IdentityModelServiceAuthorizationManager* and overriding the **CheckAccess** method as follows:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationManager : IdentityModelServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    public override bool CheckAccess(System.ServiceModel.OperationContext operationContext, ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message)
    {
        var result = base.CheckAccess(operationContext, ref message);

        var properties = operationContext.ServiceSecurityContext.AuthorizationContext.Properties;
        properties["Principal"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;

        return result;
    }
}
```

This then gets applied to the service host as follows:

```
protected override void InitializeRuntime()
{
    FederatedServiceCredentials.ConfigureServiceHost(this);
    this.Authorization.ServiceAuthorizationManager = new CustomAuthorizationManager();
    base.InitializeRuntime();
}
```

And now when I enter my service operation, I have the correct *IClaimsPrincipal* on *Thread.CurrentPrincipal*, so declarative *PrincipalPermission* now works as expected.

Comment: This solution works, however I'm not sure whether there is a bug in the existing IdentityModelServiceAuthorizationManager - my feeling is that it should be able to tell that it's running in ASP.NET Compatibility mode and therefore should be able to pull the principal from HttpContext.Current.User automatically. Should I report this to Microsoft as a bug before they ship Microsoft.IdentityModel 1.0.0.0?

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into a similar problem. I set my custom principal in the constructor of my WCF service. When I left the constructor, and entered the method I called, the thread.currentprincipal was overridden by an empty one. I solved this by adding the following behavior:

```
<serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="None"></serviceAuthorization>
```

This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

confguration settings for call **FederatedServiceCredentials.ConfigureServiceHost(this**);

is as below 
in system.serviceModel add following

```
<extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="federatedServiceHostConfiguration" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.ConfigureServiceHostBehaviorExtensionElement, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
```

under  inside add folowing line

```
<behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <federatedServiceHostConfiguration name="MyService" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that nothing is intercepting the call. Either the CurrentPrincipal is reset by the time you're examining it or you're in a different thread.

Check the CurrentPrincipal immediately after assigning to it and you should see the correct value.